# React Native rendering of componentDidMount

Tags: react-native

How to pass props from one page to another without using  navigation props?

Values can be passed by navigation props but without that how to do so?

Comment: It depends. Could you add more context to what you are trying to achieve/solve? Also . The title of the question doesnt suit the description of your questions. Can you please modify accordingly?

Comment: I am using compontDidMount in the two diffrent pages the pages gets rendered at same time which causes API to hit twice and values are updating in the table twice

Comment: Assuming you are not using state container yet, I would recommend start introducing one may be redux and move the api calls outside of components and instead use dispatch redux actions inside componentDidMount.  Then you can check for the state if a particular api call is already in progress and ignore it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question, but I will attempt an answer.  The answer of course is, it depends. If you do not want to use navigation, then I recommend you [lift up the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).  In other words, place the the props to want to pass between screens in the state of a component that is the parent of both screens. The parent component can set the props of its children based on the state.  You can use callback props on the children to set the parent components' state.

Another way to lift up the state and share data between components is to use a global state manager such as [Redux](http://redux.js.org/). This allows you to have any component set the global state and have any component take in portions of the global state as props.

Either of these options will allow you to pass data between components.